# Развертывание .NET программы

Tags: c#, .net

Развертываю программу написанную на C# (не знаю, важно ли это, но система семерка, 64 бита), устанавливаю на ноутбуке, на котором писал программу - все работает и устанавливается, пытаюсь перенести на другие компьютеры - пишет, что программа не является приложением win32. (остальные компьютеры xp 32). Связано ли с это битностью, и если да, то что делать, чтобы программу можно было запустить на системе xp 32 бита?

Comment: "опубликовал программу" - это как?

Comment: @Макс Жуков вероятно, имеется в виду publish проекта (хотя, может, и отправка исходников в газету "Сельская жизнь" для их публикации)

Comment: А с какими настройками вы компилировали? Это раз.

Затем, а есть ли на других системах .NET framework? Или она не той версии?

Или, может, вы используете библиотеку, которой нету на остальных машинах?

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего вы используете Net 4.5, который не поддерживается Windows XP, понизьте версию Framework до 4, и проверьте установлен ли он на машинах.

Comment: Еще есть вариант, что скомпилировано под X64